# Google Play Console API, статистика

Tags: google-play-console

Никак не могу найти нужный метод для того, чтобы получить статистические данные о загруженном приложении в Play Market.
Интересует: кол-во установок, кол-во удалений, оценки (средние и общие) за определенный период.
Методы для ответа на комментарии я нашёл (`androidpublisher.reviews.XXX`), а вот по статистике — никак.
Наверняка ответ на поверхности, но мне он не очевиден.